# Let $X$ be a Banach space and $U$ closed convex set s.t $\cup nU=X$ prove U contains a neighborhood of the origin.

Tags: functional-analysis

I found a solution to the problem but it uses the idea of considering the set $V=-U\cap U$ which I dislike as it seems out of nowhere (I see that it makes $V$ symmetric which is nice but the idea is out of nowhere). So I was wondering if there is an alternative way of approach this problem. Using baire category it is easy to see that $U$ must contain an open ball (Also $U$ contains 0). If we had symmetry this would be easy-ish (Hence the $V$) as then the negative of the ball is also in $U$ and then we can sum the two open balls. Can we do it some other way than considering the $V$?

Comment: The motivation for introducing $V$ is exactly that the difficulty in the naive attempt with Baire category is passing from $U$ containing some open ball to containing an open ball around the origin since you can't say immediately anything about what $U$ contains on "the opposite side of the origin to the ball you find". This makes you wish you had a symmetry condition so you look for a way to get that. Introducing the set $V$ is then the natural choice. This might be hidden by the eventual presentation of the proof but is clear from attempting to prove this yourself.